# why we pass string array in main method? WHY its not possible to pass any other argument then String cant we pass arraylist of string?

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
  public static void main1(Object[] args) {
    System.out.println("I accept an object array");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    main1(args);
  }
```

Comment: How would you pass `Object` from command line? You can only pass Strings.

Answer (score 4):

The console is a text based interface. The only thing that can be reliably passed from that interface is strings. It's up to you to parse those strings to whatever representation you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an object unless your program is *already running.*

String is a reasonable compromise; it allows all sorts of things like numbers to be also passed in as arguments.  In a pinch, you could pass in an XML representation of an object if you wanted to, and deserialize that to an object.